# Is YourFreedom a VPN?

Tags: vpn

My country disallowed VPNs a few months back and said that if someone uses it they'll have to ask for permission beforehand. And now it plans to ban some social media websites. My question is, is YourFreedom a VPN? And if I use it, can the government find out that I'm using it?

Answer (score 1):

From the manual for YourFreedom:

```
1.2 What is it not?
Your Freedom is not a VPN software. It does not provide a connection to a
private network but to the Internet.
```

If your government can inspect your Internet traffic, then they can tell that you're using it.  And you run the risk that they'll take a different view on whether or not it's a VPN.

Comment: Even though many VPNs *do* provide connections specifically to the Internet...

Comment: VPN's don't provide connections to the Internet, they provide connections to private networks which connect to the Internet -- not quite the same thing.